# Do work in thread only if CPU core idling in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am wondering if there is a way to determine, if CPU core is sleeping (do not have any work to do) and run work only in that case (in background thread).

My usecase: Let's say we have some game server that runs in ticks (Minecraft for example). I would like to save some compute heavy work to later and run it only when server is not overloaded (CPU core is not busy). I do not rally care, if this work will cause overload on core after it is being started. That probably cannot be forecasted.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156924/272724

Comment: Also you can play with the process priority: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/manipulate-process-priority

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, you can’t know this using pure Java.

The only knob that I know of related to this is the priority that you can set on a Thread. If you assign the lowest priority, you indicate that this thread should be woken up the least during scheduling. This could be done in the ThreadFactory of an ExecutorService.

Note that Thread priority is only a hint to the runtime though. There is no guarantee that setting it will have any effect.

The code being run on this Executor could occasionally call `Thread.yield`. This is another hint to the runtime to indicate that the current Thread would be ok with relinquishing its time slot to another Thread.